# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when using my own struct with pointers to array

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

Hello can you tell me why is the compiler building sucessfully when there's only one largenumber a, but when I declare another largenumber b and do the exact same things it shows  *Segmentation fault (core dumped)* . I don't understand what's wrong? I can't declare other of type largenumber because it shows segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct largenumber{
    int numbers[200];
};
typedef struct largenumber largenumber;

void insert_number_to_largenumber(int* start, int* end, char *char_number){
  int* pointer;
  int i=0;
  printf("array elements\n");
  for(pointer=start; pointer!=end; pointer++){

    switch (char_number[i]) {
      case 48 :
        *pointer = 0;
        break;
      case 49 :
        *pointer = 1;
        break;
      case 50 :
        *pointer = 2;
        break;
      case 51 :
        *pointer = 3;
        break;
      case 52 :
        *pointer = 4;
        break;
      case 53 :
        *pointer = 5;
        break;
      case 54 :
        *pointer = 6;
        break;
      case 55 :
        *pointer = 7;
        break;
      case 56 :
        *pointer = 8;
        break;
      case 57 :
        *pointer = 9;
        break;
       default:
       fprintf(stderr, "array element is not a digit!\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("a.numbers[%d] = %d \n", i, *pointer);
    i++;


  }
}

int main()
{
  char* number1;
  printf("input first number\n");
  scanf("%s", number1);
  largenumber a;
  insert_number_to_largenumber(a.numbers, a.numbers+strlen(number1), number1);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider `char_number[i]-'0'` instead of your `switch`.

Comment: The segmentation fault occurs because you declared a pointer `number1` which is not initialized, it does not point to valid memory but you try to write the input there. change it to `char number1[100]` (where `100` should be a meaningful buffer size).

Comment: Also note that after inserting you do not know how many digits you wrote in your struct, a possible solution would be to write the least significant digit first and set everything to `0` after the most significant digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `number1` uninitialized,

Use

```
char *number1 = malloc(32);
```

or

```
char number1[32];
```

before calling `scanf`, also use a width specifier in order to avoid buffer overflows:

```
scanf("%31s", number1);
```

Comment: Or even better, declare `number1` as an automatic array (`char number1[32];`), and avoid messing with dynamic allocation.